# AWS snapshots before O.S. updates

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, snapshot

I've read over the AWS Snapshot docs, but still have a question:

When taking a snapshot of an instance before doing yum updates to the O.S.:
- I have to snapshot each mounted volume separately, even the root vol, right?
- Is it best to snapshot non-root volumes while they're unmounted, rather than mounted?
- Is it best to shut down the instance before a snapshot of the root volume?

Thanks...Lyle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have multiple volumes and you want all of the snapshots to be consistent with one another your best option is to shutdown the instance.  No need to unmount the volumes.  After you start the snapshot you can turn back on the instance immediately as the snapshots will get a consistent snapshot of the drive from when you started creating the snapshot.